# Excel-vba: Get the selected cell in a cell formula using a user defined function (UDF)

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I've tried an obvious code, but it does not work.

```
Function SelectedRange(Optional ShiftRow As Long = 0, Optional ShiftColumn As Long = 0) As Range
    Set SelectedRange = Selection.Offset(ShiftRow, ShiftColumn)
End Function
```

The output is always the value of the cell with the formula (more or less the ShiftRow and the ShiftColumn) even after that I select other cells and recalculate the whole sheet manually.
What I did wrong?

Comment: Given that parameters of the function does not change, Excel doesn't know it need to recompute the result value. To force the value to be recalculated, you need to tell the function is volatile by using `Application.Volatile`

Comment: Note that selecting a cell does not entail a recalculation, so even with `Application.Volatile` your cell won't update unless you force a recalculation or modify something else.

Comment: with Application.Volatile the cell is recalculated successfully only when i press F9.

Comment: As I said, Selecting a cell does not force a recalculation (never), so the value will change only if another cell value change, or you force a recalculation (with F9 or other ways)

Comment: You can always add an `Application.Calculate` in the `SelectionChange` event if you need to.

Comment: I have already thought about this solution but for workbooks with many formulas this action would waste time at every click.

Comment: A useful trick would be to be able to calculate on SelectionChange only the cells containing that formula.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo If you know what that cell is, then you *can* calculate it manually.  E.g. if it's cell `C5`, then `Cells(5,3).Calculate` will do that

Comment: Does this need to be the full range when you have more than 1 cell selected, or just the top-left cell?  You can get the address of the top-left cell of current selection with `=CELL("address")`

Comment: what is the Scope of Application.Volatile? At level of routine, module, entire project?

Comment: `Application.Volatile` applies only to the specific Function that it appears in.

Comment: I will try your method @Chronocidal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addendum to @Gary's Student's answer, based on comments on question: when you click on a different cell in the workbook this code will find any cells with `SelectedRange` in the Formula, and Calculate those cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rTMP As Range, sTMP As String
    Set rTMP = Me.Cells.Find("SelectedRange", Me.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart)
    If Not rTMP Is Nothing Then
        sTMP = rTMP.Address
        While Not rTMP Is Nothing
            rTMP.Calculate
            Set rTMP = Me.Cells.FindNext
            If rTMP.Address = sTMP Then Set rTMP = Nothing
        Wend
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This also works on other worksheets! Great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work within a **Sub**, not a worksheet cell:

```
Function SelectedRange(Optional ShiftRow As Long = 0, Optional ShiftColumn As Long = 0) As Range
    Set SelectedRange = Selection.Offset(ShiftRow, ShiftColumn)
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim r As Range
    Range("B9").Select
    Set r = SelectedRange(1, 1)
    MsgBox r.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

To use within a worksheet cell, pass back the *address* of the selected cell(s):

```
Function SelectedRange2(Optional ShiftRow As Long = 0, Optional ShiftColumn As Long = 0) As String
    Application.Volatile
    SelectedRange2 = Selection.Offset(ShiftRow, ShiftColumn).Address(0, 0)
End Function
```

Click on the cell(s) first and touch <kbd>F9</kbd> to force calculation:

[image]

Comment: If he want to get the same value displayed as the selected cell he need to return the cell reference, not the cell address.